# Creating regular expression for html tag in c#

Tags: html, asp.net, regex, c#-2.0

I am having issue creating the regex for below tag in C#,

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:588.32px;top:443.12px" class="cls_005">652D</div>
```

I am trying this way but it is not working:

```
<div\\s+style=\"position:absolute;left:(.*)px;top:(.*)px\"\\s+class=\"cls_.*\"[^>]*>(.*)</div>
```

Comment: The regex itself is fine. Maybe something to do with your escapes.

Answer (score 0):

The input string and regex you provided seem to work.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "<div style=\"position:absolute;left:588.32px;top:443.12px\" class=\"cls_005\">652D</div>";
        var regex = new Regex("<div\\s+style=\"position:absolute;left:(.*)px;top:(.*)px\"\\s+class=\"cls_.*\"[^>]*>(.*)</div>"
            , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var m = regex.Match(input);
        if (m.Success)
            foreach (var o in m.Groups)
                Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());

        else
            Console.WriteLine("no success");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```